# target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.application'

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I build and run the app in Xcode version 4.0 Build 4A304a

I sent the zipped folder to my manager.  When he tries to build and run, he gets:

> target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.application',
>   but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

He is at version 3.2.5 64 bit

I have checked the plist, it's fine.  He is running the 4.2 sdk.

Please help!

Comment: please check this ans : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090455/xcode-getting-target-specifies-product-type-com-apple-product-type-bundle-unit

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it could be the same issue as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549633/xcode-4-5-no-com-apple-product-type-application-product-type-for-iphoneos)

Try that out and see how you go