# Xcode 4.5: no "com.apple.product-type.application" product type for iphoneos

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, xcode4.5

I just upgraded Xcode to version 4.5, but I now get this error when trying to run it on my iPhone:

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.application', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform
```

It works fine on the simulator and it used to work in version 4.4.

Comment: Please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090455/xcode-getting-target-specifies-product-type-com-apple-product-type-bundle-unit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably lost The application part from your XCode Specifications

Exit **XCode** and **Go to** (for Xcode from MacAppStore):

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/

Backup these two files before editing:  **`iPhoneOSPackageTypes.xcspec`**   **`iPhoneOSProductTypes.xcspec`**

Overwrite this content to **`iPhoneOSPackageTypes.xcspec`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>DefaultBuildSettings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(WRAPPER_NAME)</string>
        <key>DOCUMENTATION_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(LOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)/Documentation</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLES_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/Executables</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_NAME</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_PREFIX)$(PRODUCT_NAME)$(EXECUTABLE_VARIANT_SUFFIX)$(EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX)</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_PATH</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_PREFIX</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/Frameworks</string>
        <key>INFOPLIST_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/Info.plist</string>
        <key>INFOSTRINGS_PATH</key>
        <string>$(LOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)/InfoPlist.strings</string>
        <key>JAVA_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)/Java</string>
        <key>LOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)/$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE).lproj</string>
        <key>PBDEVELOPMENTPLIST_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/pbdevelopment.plist</string>
        <key>PKGINFO_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/PkgInfo</string>
        <key>PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/PlugIns</string>
        <key>PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/PrivateHeaders</string>
        <key>PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/Headers</string>
        <key>SCRIPTS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)/Scripts</string>
        <key>SHALLOW_BUNDLE</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>SHARED_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/SharedFrameworks</string>
        <key>SHARED_SUPPORT_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/SharedSupport</string>
        <key>UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>VERSIONPLIST_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/version.plist</string>
        <key>WRAPPER_NAME</key>
        <string>$(WRAPPER_PREFIX)$(PRODUCT_NAME)$(WRAPPER_SUFFIX)</string>
        <key>WRAPPER_PREFIX</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>WRAPPER_SUFFIX</key>
        <string>.bundle</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Wrapper</string>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.package-type.wrapper</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Wrapper</string>
    <key>ProductReference</key>
    <dict>
        <key>FileType</key>
        <string>wrapper.cfbundle</string>
        <key>IsLaunchable</key>
        <string>NO</string>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>$(WRAPPER_NAME)</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PackageType</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>BasedOn</key>
    <string>com.apple.package-type.wrapper</string>
    <key>DefaultBuildSettings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>GENERATE_PKGINFO_FILE</key>
        <string>YES</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Application Wrapper</string>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.package-type.wrapper.application</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Application Wrapper</string>
    <key>ProductReference</key>
    <dict>
        <key>FileType</key>
        <string>wrapper.application</string>
        <key>IsLaunchable</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>$(WRAPPER_NAME)</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PackageType</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>BasedOn</key>
    <string>com.apple.package-type.wrapper</string>
    <key>DefaultBuildSettings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(WRAPPER_NAME)/Contents</string>
        <key>DOCUMENTATION_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(LOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLES_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>INFOPLIST_PATH</key>
        <string>$(WRAPPER_NAME)/ContentInfo.plist</string>
        <key>INFOSTRINGS_PATH</key>
        <string>$(LOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)/ContentInfo.strings</string>
        <key>JAVA_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>LOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)/$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE).lproj</string>
        <key>PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>SCRIPTS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>SHARED_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>SHARED_SUPPORT_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)</string>
        <key>WRAPPER_SUFFIX</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>In-App Purchase Content</string>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.package-type.in-app-purchase-content</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>In-App Purchase Content</string>
    <key>ProductReference</key>
    <dict>
        <key>FileType</key>
        <string>folder</string>
        <key>IsLaunchable</key>
        <string>NO</string>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>$(WRAPPER_NAME)</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PackageType</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>DefaultBuildSettings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_NAME</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_PREFIX)$(PRODUCT_NAME)$(EXECUTABLE_VARIANT_SUFFIX)$(EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX)</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_PATH</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_PREFIX</key>
        <string>lib</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX</key>
        <string>.a</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Mach-O static library</string>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.package-type.static-library</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Mach-O Static Library</string>
    <key>ProductReference</key>
    <dict>
        <key>FileType</key>
        <string>archive.ar</string>
        <key>IsLaunchable</key>
        <string>NO</string>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PackageType</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

and this content to **`iPhoneOSProductTypes.xcspec`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>Class</key>
    <string>PBXBundleProductType</string>
    <key>DefaultBuildProperties</key>
    <dict>
        <key>FRAMEWORK_FLAG_PREFIX</key>
        <string>-framework</string>
        <key>FULL_PRODUCT_NAME</key>
        <string>$(WRAPPER_NAME)</string>
        <key>GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>LIBRARY_FLAG_PREFIX</key>
        <string>-l</string>
        <key>MACH_O_TYPE</key>
        <string>mh_bundle</string>
        <key>STRIP_STYLE</key>
        <string>non-global</string>
        <key>WRAPPER_EXTENSION</key>
        <string>bundle</string>
        <key>WRAPPER_NAME</key>
        <string>$(WRAPPER_PREFIX)$(PRODUCT_NAME)$(WRAPPER_SUFFIX)</string>
        <key>WRAPPER_PREFIX</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>WRAPPER_SUFFIX</key>
        <string>.$(WRAPPER_EXTENSION)</string>
    </dict>
    <key>DefaultTargetName</key>
    <string>Bundle</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Generic bundle</string>
    <key>HasInfoPlist</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>HasInfoPlistStrings</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>IconNamePrefix</key>
    <string>TargetPlugin</string>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.product-type.bundle</string>
    <key>IsWrapper</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Bundle</string>
    <key>PackageTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.package-type.wrapper</string>
    </array>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>ProductType</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>BasedOn</key>
    <string>com.apple.product-type.bundle</string>
    <key>Class</key>
    <string>PBXApplicationProductType</string>
    <key>DefaultBuildProperties</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>ENTITLEMENTS_ALLOWED</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>INSTALL_PATH</key>
        <string>$(LOCAL_APPS_DIR)</string>
        <key>MACH_O_TYPE</key>
        <string>mh_execute</string>
        <key>PROVISIONING_PROFILE_REQUIRED</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>RESOURCE_RULES_REQUIRED</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>STRIP_STYLE</key>
        <string>all</string>
        <key>WRAPPER_EXTENSION</key>
        <string>app</string>
        <key>WRAPPER_SUFFIX</key>
        <string>.$(WRAPPER_EXTENSION)</string>
    </dict>
    <key>DefaultTargetName</key>
    <string>Application</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Application</string>
    <key>IconNamePrefix</key>
    <string>TargetApp</string>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.product-type.application</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Application</string>
    <key>PackageTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.package-type.wrapper.application</string>
    </array>
    <key>SupportsZeroLink</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>ProductType</string>
    <key>Validation</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AdditionalValidationClass</key>
        <string>XCiPhoneOSPlatformPlugin</string>
        <key>Checks</key>
        <dict>
            <key>!(  $(VALIDATE_PRODUCT) == NO &amp;&amp; $(CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY) == 'iPhone Distribution'  )</key>
            <string>The Validate Built Product build setting was not enabled when building for Distribution.</string>
        </dict>
        <key>ValidationToolSpec</key>
        <string>com.apple.build-tools.platform.validate</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>Class</key>
    <string>PBXBundleProductType</string>
    <key>DefaultBuildProperties</key>
    <dict>
        <key>FULL_PRODUCT_NAME</key>
        <string>$(WRAPPER_NAME)</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>In-App Purchase Content</string>
    <key>HasInfoPlist</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>HasInfoPlistStrings</key>
    <string>NO</string>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.product-type.in-app-purchase-content</string>
    <key>IsWrapper</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>In-App Purchase Content</string>
    <key>PackageTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.package-type.in-app-purchase-content</string>
    </array>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>ProductType</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>AlwaysPerformSeparateStrip</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>Class</key>
    <string>PBXStaticLibraryProductType</string>
    <key>DefaultBuildProperties</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED</key>
        <string>NO</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_EXTENSION</key>
        <string>a</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_PREFIX</key>
        <string>lib</string>
        <key>EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX</key>
        <string>.$(EXECUTABLE_EXTENSION)</string>
        <key>FRAMEWORK_FLAG_PREFIX</key>
        <string>-framework</string>
        <key>FULL_PRODUCT_NAME</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>GCC_ENABLE_SYMBOL_SEPARATION</key>
        <string>NO</string>
        <key>INSTALL_PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/lib</string>
        <key>LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>LIBRARY_FLAG_PREFIX</key>
        <string>-l</string>
        <key>MACH_O_TYPE</key>
        <string>staticlib</string>
        <key>PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/include</string>
        <key>PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/include</string>
        <key>REZ_EXECUTABLE</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>SEPARATE_STRIP</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>STRIP_STYLE</key>
        <string>debugging</string>
    </dict>
    <key>DefaultTargetName</key>
    <string>Static Library</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Static library</string>
    <key>IconNamePrefix</key>
    <string>TargetLibrary</string>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.product-type.library.static</string>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Static Library</string>
    <key>PackageTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.package-type.static-library</string>
    </array>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>ProductType</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Restart XCode then Clean your Project and build it again for you device.

Comment: please check this ans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090455/xcode-getting-target-specifies-product-type-com-apple-product-type-bundle-unit

Answer (score 8):

edit: It can also be that the project expects you to have http://www.iosopendev.com/ installed.

My error was "target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.library.dynamic', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform"

Inside of the appropriate directory, per TwiterZX's's comment, run the following commands:

```
sudo plutil -convert json iPhoneOSProductTypes.xcspec
sudo plutil -convert json iPhoneOSPackageTypes.xcspec
```

Editing these files can be made a lot easier if you use a json pretty service on your file's contents first.

After the first [ inside of iPhoneOSProductTypes.xcspec, paste:

```
{   "Type": "ProductType",
    "Identifier": "com.apple.product-type.library.dynamic",
    "Class": "PBXDynamicLibraryProductType",
    "Name": "Dynamic Library",
    "Description": "Dynamic library",
    "IconNamePrefix": "TargetPlugin",
    "DefaultTargetName": "Dynamic Library",
    "DefaultBuildProperties": {
        "FULL_PRODUCT_NAME": "$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)",
        "MACH_O_TYPE": "mh_dylib",
        "REZ_EXECUTABLE": "YES",
        "EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX": ".$(EXECUTABLE_EXTENSION)",
        "EXECUTABLE_EXTENSION": "dylib",
        "PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH": "/usr/local/include",
        "PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH": "/usr/local/include",
        "INSTALL_PATH": "/usr/local/lib",
        "DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE": "$(INSTALL_PATH)",
        "LD_DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME": "$(DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE:standardizepath)/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)",
        "DYLIB_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION": "1",
        "DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION": "1",
        "FRAMEWORK_FLAG_PREFIX": "-framework",
        "LIBRARY_FLAG_PREFIX": "-l",
        "LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE": "YES",
        "STRIP_STYLE": "debugging",
        "GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN": "YES",
        "CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED": "YES"
    },
    "PackageTypes": [
        "com.apple.package-type.mach-o-dylib"
    ]
},
```

After the first [ inside of iPhoneOSPackageTypes.xcspec, paste:

```
{   "Type": "PackageType",
    "Identifier": "com.apple.package-type.mach-o-dylib",
    "Name": "Mach-O Dynamic Library",
    "Description": "Mach-O dynamic library",
    "DefaultBuildSettings": {
        "EXECUTABLE_PREFIX": "",
        "EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX": "",
        "EXECUTABLE_NAME": "$(EXECUTABLE_PREFIX)$(PRODUCT_NAME)$(EXECUTABLE_VARIANT_SUFFIX)$(EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX)",
        "EXECUTABLE_PATH": "$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)"
    },
    "ProductReference": {
        "FileType": "compiled.mach-o.dylib",
        "Name": "$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)",
        "IsLaunchable": "NO"
    }
},
```

Now you need to convert those files back to binary:

```
sudo plutil -convert binary1 iPhoneOSProductTypes.xcspec
sudo plutil -convert binary1 iPhoneOSPackageTypes.xcspec
```

That should do it!

Comment: Also, you can edit this file without converting it right inside a good plist editing app, such as [Plist Edit Pro](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/plisteditpro/)(no affiliation ).