# XCode getting "target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.bundle.unit-test', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xcode6

When running my project in XCode, my tests gives this error:

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.bundle.unit-test', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform
```

It happened after a couple of XCode updates. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It looks like Xcode 6 changed the product identifier for ocunit test bundles from `com.apple.product-type.bundle` to `com.apple.product-type.bundle.ocunit-test`.

Edit `$(ProjectName).xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and replace any instance of `com.apple.product-type.bundle.ocunit-test` with `com.apple.product-type.bundle`. For now you will need to do this any time you open your project with Xcode 6 and then want to open it in Xcode 5.

Comment: This needs to earn more than just up votes. The original poster needs to check this as the answer.

Comment: @AlexPretzlav how do I edit project name and the ocunit-test? I can't find instances of those, but I'm getting the exact same error.

Comment: @TheveshTheva edit the file called `project.pbxproj` inside your `.xcodeproj` file (it may look like a file, but it's actually a folder, use Terminal)

Comment: Really it needs more up votes, unfortunately I can give only one but it deserves 100 dude, I have been trying for last two hours and haven't found  right solution. But your answer helped a lot.

Comment: I have same error but How can I change it. I am New for all this stuff can any one give me step by step instruction. Thanks

Comment: This Answer is more easier than all this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914765/com-apple-product-type-bundle-ui-testing-but-theres-no-such-product-type-for-t

Answer (score 1):

What Worked for me was:

1. Delete the launchScreen.storyboard (Move to trash).
2. Create a new launchScreen.storyboard..From File -> new File ->iOS User Interface -> LaunchScreen (I named the same AND! checked marked for all the targets at the bottom)
3. Change Deployment Target from 9.1 which is the one I created my project with to 8.3 (this was done for the project and the targets)
4. Up to this point I was still getting the same error
5. I just deleted ProjectNameUITest from this section in Xcode  [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whdCY.png)