# target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.bundle.ui-testing', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

When i was running my swift project, I got this error.

> target specifies product type
>   '***com.apple.product-type.bundle.ui-testing***', but there's no such
>   product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

I found some similar questions on SO but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090455/xcode-getting-target-specifies-product-type-com-apple-product-type-bundle-unit) answer didn't solve my problem. I [googled](https://www.google.com.pe/search?q=com.apple.product-type.bundle.ui-testing&oq=com.apple.product-type.bundle.ui-testing&aqs=chrome..69i57.348j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=%22com.apple.product-type.bundle.ui-testing%22) it too, there are no project with this product type inside.

I'm using xcode 6.4 and swift 1.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had this issue after adding a product for UI testing using Xcode 7 Beta and constantly switching between Xcode 6.4 and 7 Beta. A simple **clean** made it go away.

Comment: Thanks. I tried other options but this is the only one that worked.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, clean did not work.

Open `AppName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`, replace **all** `com.apple.product-type.*` (there are 3 of them) with `com.apple.product-type.application` solved my problem.

It seems apple changed the type name in Xcode 7.

Comment: How do you access `AppName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` ? I'm having this same problem

Comment: @kebabTiger Use Finder or Terminal, open with any text editor you like.