# com.apple.product-type.bundle.ui-testing, but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator, swift2

I used Xcode 7 Beta to develop this project

and now I switch to Xcode 6.4

So I had this issue now

and i have tried clean, but it doesn't work

target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.bundle.ui-testing', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

Comment: In the same situation, used Xcode 7 to develop and encountered the same error when opening the project with 6.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are not using UI Testing, you can delete the UITest target in your project's build settings.

[image]